# foreach debugging is too detailed

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2008

First apologies for the title, it's a bit hard to describe the problem in a short summary.

While debugging C# code in Visual Studio 2008, I notice that pressing F10 (step over) while at a `foreach` loop results in the debugger simply stopping at almost each keyword inside the `foreach`. For example:

```
foreach( int foo in fooList )
```

If my breakpoint is set to this line, and after pressing F10, it highlights `int foo`, then F10 again highlights `fooList` then F10 again highlights `in`. Finally after pressing F10 about 4 times it steps to the first line of code inside the `foreach`. This is really annoying and I expect that pressing F10 will skip to over the `foreach` line in one shot (like it does while debugging C++ for loops). Is there a way to configure this in Visual Studio or do I have to live with it? :-(

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the loop body, then hit F5.

Comment: BTW, it's stopping at the generated calls to `MoveNext()` and `Current`.

Comment: @SLaks Well obviously I've thought of the 2nd breakpoint idea, but would much prefer having a toggle to disable "detailed" foreach inspection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add breakpoints to the start and ending braces, which is what I typically do.

For example:

```
foreach(Item item in collection)
{    // <- Breakpoint here for the start of each iteration

     // Do some work here.

}    // <- Breakpoint here for the end of each iteration
```

Also, use F5 to continue execution until the next breakpoint. F10 will only step a single 'instruction'.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it's very detailed. I like the idea of putting the breakpoint on the opening brace. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Add a breakpoint inside foreach and use F5

Answer (score 1):

Here are the following shortcut keys (default which can be changed if desired) in Visual Studio:

- **F11 - Step Into** - Execute code one statement at a time, following execution into function calls (Step Into).
- **F10 - Step Over** - Execute the next line of code but not follow execution through any function calls (Step Over).
- **Shift + F11 - Step Out** - Execute the remaining lines of a function in which the current execution point lies (Step Out).
- **F5 - Continue** - Runs the application.  If you have any additional break point the application will naturally stop at that point.  So if this break point is in a foreach loop it will stop each time that loop is executed.

Here is a helpful link with all debugger shortcut codes: [Shortcut Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239052%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: The asker is looking for a setting in the debugging options to change how the debugger moves through for loops, not a list of debugger keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: The asker doesn't understand the debugging tools so I gave a quick list so they know what hitting F5 will do for them and what hitting F10, what they were doing before, was actually doing.